# Receiving integers from the user until they enter 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

It's my 2nd week in programming in Python and have never programmed anything before. appreciate step by step.

I don't know where to start.

Comment: What have you got so far? Do you know how to read a single number? Do you know how to read multiple numbers? Do you know about loops? Show us whatever code you do have.

Comment: Maybe start with receiving integers from the user (hint: this operation consists of two steps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    count = 0
    while True:
        user = int(input('Insert Number: '))
        count += user
        if user == 0:
            break
    print(count)
except ValueError:
    print('Please Insert Numbers Only!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a start, use a while loop for the input. I'll leave the summation part for you unless you need further help:

```
cc = int(input("Enter an integer to sum. Press 0 to to end and start the summation:"))
while cc != 0:
    cc = int(input("Enter an integer to sum. Press 0 to to end and start the summation:"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_int(num):
    try:
        return int(num)
    except:
        return False

total = 0
while True:
    in_user = is_int(input("input integer: "))
    if in_user is not False:
        total += in_user
    if in_user is 0:
        break

print(total)
```